Adding a connection from Azure Web App to GitHub using Deployment center
We are trying to push an app from GitHub to Azure Web App. In GitHub I am an owner of an organization called DNA:

In the org the repo we would like to deploy exists:

In Azure I go to the "Deployment center" and choose GitHub in the source. I sign in with my account but I only see my personal repos and not repos from the org. What can cause this?

The only org I can choose are is my own profile:


Did you select the correct Organization?

I have updated the post. Only org I can choose I are my own profile. See image in post.

Grant Access to your organization under profile=>settings=>Applications=>Authorized OAuth Apps=>click on Grant. Refer image

Follow below steps to see the multiple(or) specific organizations in the drop down of Organization under Deployment=>Source=>GitHub.

Go to your profile in GitHub, open Settings=>Applications.
Navigate to Authorized OAuth Apps, select Azure App Service.



You can see your organization which requires access under Organization Access, click on Grant to allow the organization to control the application deployment to Azure App Service.


While creating Azure App Service, navigate to Deployment section=> Source=> GitHub, click on Authorize, you can see your organization. click on Grant=> Authorize AzureAppService.

Now, you will be able to see all your organizations and repositories.

You can see all the repositories available under the selected organization.

